# Designing difficulty position not accurate

Tags: css

I have a table in which I have a dropdown, due to IE8, I had to manipulate it such that it displays long text in the option.  However, upon resizing the window, the dropdown isn`t being resized and is being shown as in the image attached. That`s look funny. How can I correct the dropdown being shown such that when window is being resized, it also gets resized along.

style is as follows: `.test{
    width: 250px;
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:+1;
}` 
code is as follows:

```
 <select id="myList" class= "test" onactivate="this.style.width='auto';"    onchange="this.blur();"    onblur="this.style.width='250px';"  disabled>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Give the `select` a width in `%` rather than `px`.
Or use some javascript to handle the window's resize event.